# changing tokeniput jquery plugin to allow values to be hyperlinked?

Tags: php, jquery, json, plugins, autosuggest

i really love this jquery plugin called jquery tokeninput, but i want to know how i could change it to make the values autosuggested to be hyperlinked so they take you to another page! this plugin only lets you add values to textfield like tagging, thanks

the pluging is located here:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

the code is here for the plugin is here:

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either the `onAdd` or `onResult` callbacks. The `onAdd` doesn't allow you to edit the result so I had to use a selector to edit the token.

The JSON data also seems to only intrepret `id` and `name`. If it supported a `value` then the displayed value wouldn't have to match the url. I believe the [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) supports that.

http://jsfiddle.net/sATcY/1